# Is $A-\left(A-B\right)=B$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $A-\left(A-B\right)=B$ but I've arrived to this instead:

$A-\left(A-B\right)=A\cap \overline{\left(A\cap \overline{B}\right)}=A\cap \left(\overline{A}\cup B\right)=\left(A \cap \overline{A} \right)\cup \left( A \cap B\right)=\emptyset \cup \left( A \cap B\right)=\left( A \cap B\right) \neq B$

Is this correct? The first step is to use a logical equivalence, then de Morgan's law, distributive laws and other logical equivalences, I think I am following the rules. If this happens to be correct should the equal sign have to change to a subset sign so the statement holds?

Kind Regards

Comment: $\{1,2\} - (\{1,2\} - \{2,3\}) = \{1,2\} - \{1\} = \{2\}$ and this is $\{1,2\} \cap \{2,3\}$, not $\{2,3\}$...

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: Yes this is all correct. $\subseteq$ would make the statement true.

Comment: What is your universe? With respect to what are you taking complements?

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help! XD I never thought to draw a Venn diagram, but it seems that the question has that typo. This can be closed now. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A-(A-B) A,B \subset E.$

$A-B=\{x \in A , x\notin B\}$

$A-(A-B)= \{x \in A, x \notin (A-B)\}$

$x \notin (A-B)\implies x\notin A $ or ($x \in A$ and $x \in B)$

We have $x \in A$, so we also must have $x \in  B$.

So $x\in A-(A-B) \implies x \in A \cap B$.

Equivalence doesn't necessarily appply.

$A \cap B=B$ iff $B  \subset A  $.

Answer (score 3):

You correctly proved $A-(A-B)=A\cap B$. Consequently, $A-(A-B)=B$ is true if and only if $A\cap B=B$. You may know that the latter is true if and only if $B\subseteq A$. Hence *in general*, $A-(A-B)=B$ is *not* true.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is empty and $B$ is not, the equality is obviously false

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the universe, then the statement is true due to your argument. In that case $A\cap B = B$.